# How to make my python script executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to make my script executable. I used pyinstaller to transform my script into an 'exe'. However, after I transformed it when I double click the 'exe' file it opens a command window and closes it within 0.5 seconds.

My script creates a class that executes functions. The purpose of the script is automatically generate a report from a website, process the report, and export it to a database.

My last few lines prompts the user to input their username, password, month, and year. Then it runs the class functions with the prompted inputs.

Is there something missing in my script or am I writing it wrong?

I am using Windows 7, pycharm as my IDE, my project interpreter is anaconda/python 2.7.

Here is my script, it does not contain the class function because it is too long. But, everything works fine when I run it in pycharm.

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import time
import datetime as dt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

class Cybersource(object):...

username = raw_input("username: ")
password = raw_input("password: ")
month = raw_input("month (example: 07): ")
year = raw_input("year (example: 2015): ")

test = Cybersource(username,password,month,year)
test.scraper()
test.rename()
test.clean()
```

I want to make my script executable so I can run it faster without opening pycharm or hand it off to other people.

Please let me know if there are any questions.

Thanks

Comment: First, does it work if you start the program from a `cmd.exe` window by running `python script.py`? Second, does the `script.exe` run properly when started from a `cmd.exe` window?

Comment: please see [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html), they are quite clear about it

Comment: @RolandSmith python script.py runs fine. When I run the script.exe it opens another command window and closes within 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @IamnotGeorge Since the script itself runs fine, the problem seems to lie with `py2exe`. Try contacting the developers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your script.exe from cmd (not with double click) and post the exact error?

Comment: Error loading Python DLL: C:\Users\build\DATAPO~1\python277.dll (error code 126)

Comment: I belive this might help : https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#understanding-pyinstaller-hooks
and also read parts with a.binaries

Comment: Try adding to the .spec
 a.binaries + [('python277.dll', 'path to python277.dll', 'BINARY')]